# Select repeating number x times and then increment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query

I need a select query that can generate `z` amount of rows starting from 1, repeating `x` times and then increment to the next number.

For example 10 rows repeating 4 times would result in the following:

```
| # |  
|---|  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 1 |  
| 2 |  
| 2 |  
| 2 |  
| 2 |  
| 3 |  
| 3 |
```

So z=10 and x=4 in the example given. These are parameters of a stored procedure. There are no limits or restrictions. The user can enter 2 billion if user needs 2 billion (unlikely).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```sql
DECLARE @z INT=10, @x INT=4;
WITH q AS (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM q)
SELECT TOP(@z) n/@x+1 FROM q OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Technically, `TOP` needs an `ORDER BY` clause in the same scope to guarantee correct results. Recursive CTEs are not the most efficient way to generate numbers on the fly (not a particular concern if `@z` is small enough).

Answer (score 2):

One solution using simple integer arithmetic on a table of numbers. This example uses an efficient way to generate a sequence on the fly, in practice you would probably have a [permanent Numbers table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/).

```
DECLARE
    @z bigint = 10,
    @x integer = 4;

-- Itzik Ben-Gan's row generator
WITH
  L0   AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
  Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS n FROM L5)
-- Main logic
SELECT TOP (@z)
    # = ((N.n - 1) / @x) + 1
FROM Nums AS N
ORDER BY N.n;
```

Output:

```
╔═══╗
║ # ║
╠═══╣
║ 1 ║
║ 1 ║
║ 1 ║
║ 1 ║
║ 2 ║
║ 2 ║
║ 2 ║
║ 2 ║
║ 3 ║
║ 3 ║
╚═══╝
```

Execution plan:

[image: plan]

Answer (score 1):

## PostgreSQL

This can be easily done with PostgreSQL using [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)

```sql
SELECT t.x
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(x)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1,4) AS g(x)
ORDER BY t.x;
```

Here we generate a series `[1..10]` and then repeat it four times.

Output

```sql
 x  
----
  1
  1
  1
  1
  2
  2
  2
  2
  3
  3
  3
  3
```